# how to remove an element from an array with LODASH / UNDERSCORE

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have a list of items with the option to checked / unchecked them whether you want to see them or not in another view.

right now I have a `post` request where I am saving all the elements that the user unchecked. this is what I have saved so far, printed in the console looks like this

```
[ { sport: [ 9, 19, 58, 18, 24, 4, 8 ] } ]
```

now the issue: if I checked again any of those elements, the one I checked must disappear from that list, but still persist in the DB whether I checked it or unchecked it.

this is the part where I need to perform the mentioned above

```
      if (_.includes(sportChecked.sport, params.sport)) {
        sportChecked.sport = _.difference(newSport, params.sport);
        console.log(sportChecked.sport);
      }else {
        newSport.push(params.sport);
        sportChecked.sport = newSport;
      }
```

as you see I am using `_.difference` to tell the user that the sport he is trying to unchecked is already on the list.

this `console.log(sportChecked.sport);` is the one which shows me the array that I am printing in the terminal. So what can I do to delete from the list the checked items using `lodash` ?

**Update**

watching this from another point, could be: non element on the array must be there if you checked the element in the DOM, if the element is already in the list, I have there _.difference for that, so, once the user checked the item in the DOM, let's say the element with the id 9 which is the first element on that array, then that element doesn't must be there anymore.

Comment: look at the _.omit function

Comment: _.omit omits from an object.  I think this is a case for _.filter.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty can you help me with a little piece of code ?